# Kendo angular directives

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Angular 1.5.* together with Kendo UI.  I am following the documentation and have completed all the recommended steps found on the Telerik site:

1. Including the kendo scripts and styles
2. Adding kendo.directives to my angular module
3. Using the kendo-[directive] syntax in the markup

Everything renders fine, but when I try to interact with the widgets I am getting the following error:
**Uncaught TypeError: f.getClientRects is not a function(…)**

This is what my markup looks like:

```html
<input kendo-date-picker ng-model="model.user.dob" />
```

The same error happens when I try to use a drop down list defined as:

```html
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-source="model.languages" ng-model="model.user.language"></select>
```

I have used Kendo for years, but for the first time, I am using it together with Angular and feel a little lost :)

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2804

Comment: Thank you Anton,  I wonder if this is the same issue.  It seems that the problem described in the link is related to jsdom.  I am not using that.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you have the kendo scripts in the right dependency order

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Another thing that might work for older versions of kendo, is trying the deprecated angular-kendo npm package

```
<script src="./bower_components/angular-kendo/angular-kendo.js"></script>
```

Or, it could be caused from the animations so try angular-animate npm package:

```
<script src="./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Another thing you might want to check is the date going into the Kendo DatePicker

`$scope.model.user.dob = new Date('2016-06-01T04:00:00');`

Comment: Thank you DDrake.  I was using an older version of kendo.  Once I updated, everything works well.  False alarm :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was in the kendo version I was using.  Once I upgraded to the latest build, everything went back to normal.